# Getting distinct values using tiered criteria

Tags: sql, select, datatables, distinct, criteria

I am trying to figure out how to take a table with with thousands of records and distill it down based on a few criteria. However the criteria are tiered. Its best explained by an example:

| Product Key | Product Code | Qty Bundle | Product Group | Product Expiry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 000ABC | 1 | Widgets | null |
| 2 | 000ABC | 5 | Widgets | null |
| 3 | 000ABC | 1 | Widgets | null |
| 4 | 000ABC | 10 | Widgets | null |
| 5 | 000DEF | 1 | Widgets | null |
| 6 | 000DEF | 10 | Widgets | 01/15/2021 |
| 7 | 000DEF | 10 | Widgets | null |
| 8 | 000HIJ | 5 | Widgets | 11/20/2020 |
| 9 | 000HIJ | 10 | Widgets | null |
| 10 | 000HIJ | 5 | Widgets | null |

Using the above as the example data, what I would want to end up with is a list where for each Product Code we are only returning a single Product Key. The criteria would be: if the product code has a Qty Bundle value = 1 then use that product key, if there are multiple Qty Bundles = 1 for a Product Code and both those Product Keys have not expired take the minimum Product Key, and if there are no Qty Bundle = 1 for a product code, simply take the minimum product key that is not expired.

Based on those criteria, the result of the script should yield:

| Product Key | Product Code | Qty Bundle | Product Group | Product Expiry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 000ABC | 1 | Widgets | null |
| 5 | 000DEF | 1 | Widgets | null |
| 9 | 000HIJ | 10 | Widgets | null |

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: What if there are rows with "1" but all the rows are expired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with appropriate ordering criteria:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by productcode
                                order by (case when qty_bundle = 1 and expiry is null then 1
                                               else 2
                                          end),
                                         (case when expiry is not null then 1 else 2
                                               else 3
                                          end),
                                         productkey
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon - this works great! Really appreciate the help!